# SQL Server Value <> Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, sql-server-2012

We have a uniqueidentifier column in one of our SQL tables which is set as the primary key. For various reasons we don't want this to be auto-generated by SQL.

I want to be able to add a constraint on this column to disallow the value '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

Can this be easily achieved?

Comment: Can't you add a `CHECK` constraint that's basically `Column <> '000000-...'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table YourTable add constraint CHK_YourTable_GUID 
    check (guid <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04b5c/1/0)